# Bash check array for existing directories

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement

Why does an empty variable test true if I check for existing directory?

I have two array's with a couple of dirs to process, which I loop / check like this:

```
for n in {1..20}
do
   if test -d ${dir[$n]}
   then
       echo "Execute ${dir[$n]}"
   fi
   if test -d ${other[$n]}
   then
       echo "Execute ${other[$n]}"
   fi 
done
```

However, after execution of the existing dirs the script also tries to execute the none existing array elements. It does not matter if I check for dir, file or even nonempty file.
Why?

Of course I can do a separate check if an element exists before checking if the dir exist, but can I not do this in one check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your ${foo[$n]} in double quotes:

```
if test -d "${dir[$n]}"
```

Consider:

```
$ test -d '' || echo false
false
$ test -d || echo false
$
```

In general, *always* put variable dereferences into double quotes. If you don't and a variable is undefined then bad things happen, as you're seeing here.

Comment: Sometimes life can be so easy :) Thanks!

Comment: I'd consider it to be a bug in `test`: Actually it should output a "syntax error" and exit with some error code different from 1. Doing an `strace` showed that test did not test anything for `test -d`.